# updating trac timeline automatically

Tags: svn, trac

My svn revisions are not showing on the trac timeline every time I commit. I have to resync the repository in order to make the updates appear. I want the revisions to appear on the timeline without me having to resynchronize the revisions with:

```
trac-admin /path/to/trac/env repository resync '*'
```

In the trac.ini file in the `[components]` section I have: 
`tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.* = enabled`

and in the timeline section I have:

```
[timeline]
abbreviated_messages = true
changeset_collapse_events = false
changeset_long_messages = false
changeset_show_files = 0
default_daysback = 30
max_daysback = 90
newticket_formatter = oneliner
ticket_show_details = true
```

How can I do to make the svn commits appear on the timeline without having to resync or sync the repository?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, which are documented on the [TracRepositoryAdmin](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin) page.

1. Setup [Explicit Synchronization](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#ExplicitSync)
2. Set the repository [sync_per_request](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#Repositories) attribute to True.

The former is recommended. The latter is simpler to setup, and may be fine as a starting point. If you have slow page load times with per-request synchronization you can switch to explicit synchronization.

I've assumed you are using Trac 1.2.x. If you are using Trac 1.0.x, the `[trac] repositories_sync_per_request` option should be used rather than the `sync_per_request` attribute of a repository. See the [1.0 documentation](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/1.0/TracRepositoryAdmin) for details.

I can revise the answer with more detailed info if you provide the following:

- Trac version
- Whether you've configured repositories in the `[repositories]` section of trac.ini or through the Admin repositories page.